Verifying Center of Mass to Lab frame transformation for Yukawa cross section
I have computed the Yukawa-potential cross section for two spinless particles with mass ration $\lambda \equiv m_P/m_T$; where $m_P$ is the projectile mass and $m_T$ is the target mass. I want to verify that computing the cross section in either the Lab or Center of Mass (CoM) frame directly results in the same answer as computing the cross section in the CoM frame and transforming to the lab.
I am using the following reference for most of my guidance:
Taylor, John, R. "Scattering Theory: The Quantum Theory of Nonrelativistic Collisions"
Dover (2006) [republication of John Wiley & Sons 1972]
Problem Setup
I am interested in the non-relativistic treatment and I shall refer to this reference as ST. Throughout ST natural units are used ($\hbar$=$c$=1). In the reference the Yukawa potential is written as:
\begin{equation*}
V(r) = \gamma \frac{e^{-\mu r}}{r},
\end{equation*}
where $\mu$ is real and positive. Generically, the differential cross section should be:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} = \frac{k_f}{k_i} \frac{4\gamma^2 m^2}{\left ( \mu^2 + q^2 \right )^2}, 
\end{equation*}
where $k_{f,i}$ are the final and initial wave numbers; $m$ is the projectile mass; and $q$ is the magnitude of the vector $\vec{k}_f-\vec{k}_i$. In the CoM frame $k_f$ = $k_i$ so:
\begin{equation*}
\left ( \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} \right )_{CoM} = \frac{4\gamma^2 m^2}{\left ( \mu^2 + 2k_i^2(1-\cos{\theta_{cm}})\right)^2}.
\end{equation*}
Now, I can also write the cross section in the Lab frame as this:
\begin{equation}
\left ( \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} \right )_{LAB} = \sqrt{\frac{E_f}{E_i}}\frac{4\gamma^2 m^2}{\left ( \mu^2 + k_f^2 + k_i^2 - 2k_fk_i\cos{\theta}\right)^2},
\end{equation}
where all kinematic factors like $E_{i,f}$, $k_{i,f}$ and $\theta$ should be calculated in the Lab frame. The square root of the ratio of the energies comes from the fraction $k_f/k_i$ and can be expressed easily using the kinematic relationship:
\begin{equation}
(E_i-E_f) = E_i \alpha (1 - \cos{\theta_{cm}}),
\end{equation}
And $\alpha$ can be expressed like $2\lambda/(\lambda+1)^2$.
The Question
Instead of computing both cross sections in their own frames I can use the relationship between the cross sections on pg 66 of ST.
\begin{equation}
\left ( \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} \right )_{LAB} = \left ( \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} \right )_{CoM} \frac{\left (1 + 2\lambda\cos{\theta_{cm}} + \lambda^2 \right )^{3/2}}{|1+\lambda \cos{\theta_{cm}}|}.
\end{equation}
I was able to verify this equation by changing variables in the solid angles and using the relationship:
\begin{equation}
\tan{\theta} = \frac{\sin{\theta_{cm}}}{\cos{\theta_{cm}}+\lambda}
\end{equation}
My problem is that I can't verify the frame transformation method analytically or numerically. The code below is meant to verify it numerically in Python.
ct = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,100)
mu = 1
ki = 10
def alpha(lam=1):
    return 2*lam/(lam+1)**2

def coslab(lam=1,ct=1.0):
    return (ct+lam)/np.sqrt(1+2*lam*ct+lam**2)

def jacobian(lam=1,ct=1.0):
    return (1+2*lam*ct+lam**2)**(3/2)/(np.abs(1+lam*ct)+1e-6) #regularize denomonator by adding epsilon=1e-6
def dsigCM(lam=1,ct=1.0):
    return 1/(mu**2+2*ki**2*(1-ct))**2

def kiLAB(lam=1):
    return ki*(lam+1)

def kfLAB(lam=1,ct=1.0):
    return kiLAB(lam)*np.sqrt(1-alpha(lam)*(1-ct))

def dsigLAB(lam=1,ct=1.0):
    return np.sqrt(1-alpha(lam)+alpha(lam)*ct)*(1/(mu**2+kfLAB(lam,ct)**2+kiLAB(lam)**2-2*kiLAB(lam)*kfLAB(lam,ct)*coslab(lam,ct))**2)

The results make sense for $\lambda$ very small (in that case the CoM and LAB frames are the same):
print(dsigCM(1e-7,ct)/dsigLAB(1e-7,ct))
[1.0000002  1.0000002  1.0000002  1.00000019 1.00000019 1.00000019
 1.00000019 1.00000019 1.00000018 1.00000018 1.00000018 1.00000018
 1.00000018 1.00000017 1.00000017 1.00000017 1.00000017 1.00000017
 1.00000016 1.00000016 1.00000016 1.00000016 1.00000016 1.00000015
 1.00000015 1.00000015 1.00000015 1.00000015 1.00000014 1.00000014
 1.00000014 1.00000014 1.00000014 1.00000013 1.00000013 1.00000013
 1.00000013 1.00000013 1.00000012 1.00000012 1.00000012 1.00000012
 1.00000012 1.00000011 1.00000011 1.00000011 1.00000011 1.00000011
 1.0000001  1.0000001  1.0000001  1.0000001  1.00000009 1.00000009
 1.00000009 1.00000009 1.00000009 1.00000008 1.00000008 1.00000008
 1.00000008 1.00000008 1.00000007 1.00000007 1.00000007 1.00000007
 1.00000007 1.00000006 1.00000006 1.00000006 1.00000006 1.00000006
 1.00000005 1.00000005 1.00000005 1.00000005 1.00000005 1.00000004
 1.00000004 1.00000004 1.00000004 1.00000004 1.00000003 1.00000003
 1.00000003 1.00000003 1.00000003 1.00000002 1.00000002 1.00000002
 1.00000002 1.00000002 1.00000001 1.00000001 1.00000001 1.00000001
 1.00000001 1.         1.         1.        ]

But trying to do so for other values of $\lambda$ results in:
print(jacobian(10,ct)*dsigCM(10,ct)/dsigLAB(10,ct))
[   98.999989     101.77840405   104.68741438   107.73644926
   110.93586809   114.29707798   117.83266969   121.55657519
   125.48425113   129.63289334   134.02168847   138.67211069
   143.60827309   148.8573459    154.45005681   160.42129292
   166.81082922   173.66421562   181.03386455   188.98039392
   197.57429825   206.89804568   217.04873284   228.14147892
   240.31381073   253.73139356   268.59561566   285.15376573
   303.7129001    324.65906064   348.48441753   375.82643097
   407.52573568   444.71409512   488.95237722   542.45521621
   608.47333194   691.97967877   800.9841275    949.26942362
  1162.73499878  1496.46270212  2091.93711565  3455.7631574
  9778.91198979 12000.86799045  3739.60792341  2222.22
  1584.47598749  1233.35817862  1011.09082479   857.74352778
   745.56326302   659.93452465   592.42826111   537.8418505
   492.79017997   454.97572272   422.78423102   395.04830758
   370.90279379   349.69290389   330.91394625   314.17064742
   299.14902412   285.59650789   273.30762924   262.11352795
   251.87414726   242.47234355   233.80938478   225.80147003
   218.3770098    211.4744799    205.04071257   199.0295243
   193.40060549   188.11861537   183.15243926   178.47457523
   174.0606245    169.88886582   165.93989796   162.19633803
   158.64256565   155.2645051    152.04943902   148.98584835
   146.0632745    143.27220002   140.60394508   138.05057732
   135.60483306   133.2600483    131.01009811   128.84934316
   126.77258256   124.77501206   122.85218694   120.999989  ]

What is going on here--where is the flaw in my logic? Have I interpreted the transformation equation incorrectly? Currently I'm thinking that I can write the differential cross section in the lab in terms of $\theta_{cm}$ for checking of the equation purposes. So that's what I do in the code for the Lab cross section, get all the values in the Lab frame in terms of the CoM angle; I have helper functions to transform stuff.
